# HTML Email text formatting - Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, html-email

I have created an email template and when running tests a strange icon shows up in one of the paragraphs when viewed in Outlook 2013.

[image]

The strange icon is between the words 'paying' and 'off'

Does anyone have any ideas on how to hide this icon

EDIT:

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding:0 0 0 15px;">
        <div style="font-family: Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#FFFFFF;display:inline-block;">Great if you don’t pay off your card every month, or if you are paying off another card with a higher interest rate – saving you money.</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please include the portion of the email template that relates to this text?

Comment: Added the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something you've already done - but have you tried deleting "paying off" and reytping it manually?

I can't replicate the problem copying the supplied code, so whatever that strange character is must have been stripped out by the stackoverflow editor.

I've encountered similar issues when copy and pasting text from pdfs, it looks perfect in the editor but Outlook attempts (and fails) to display invisible elements that the pdf includes for some reason.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I closed and re-opened the file before manually writing the text in again. It was strange how it only displayed the weird icon in Outlook 2013 and no other Outlooks

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the character set for your HTML page? Perhaps it's using the wrong encoding.

See this [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)

```
The HTML charset Attribute

To display an HTML page correctly, a web browser must know the character set used in the page.

This is specified in the <meta> tag:
For HTML4:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
For HTML5:
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thanks matt, I did change from HTML4 to HTML5 and used the correct doctype and character set :)